# How to remove duplicate values inside a list array in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have many records in one collection in MongoDB and this is 3 examples to remove only based one QUESTION match criteria.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f0f561256efe82f5082252e"
  },
  "Item1": false,
  "Item2": "",
  "Item3": 1,
  "Item4": [
    {
      "Name": "TYPE",
      "Value": "QUESTION"
    },
    {
      "Name": "QUESTION",
      "Value": "What is your name?"
    },
    {
      "Name": "CORRECT_ANSWER",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "ANSWER_1",
      "Value": "name one"
    },
    {
      "Name": "ANSWER_2",
      "Value": "name two"
    }
  ],
  "Item5": [
    10
  ],
  "Item6": false
}
```

and another one to compare

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f0f561256efe82f5082252c"
  },
  "Item1": false,
  "Item2": "",
  "Item3": 2,
  "Item4": [
    {
      "Name": "TYPE",
      "Value": "QUESTION"
    },
    {
      "Name": "QUESTION",
      "Value": "What is your name?"
    },
    {
      "Name": "CORRECT_ANSWER",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "ANSWER_1",
      "Value": "name one"
    },
    {
      "Name": "ANSWER_2",
      "Value": "name two"
    }
  ],
  "Item5": [
    10
  ],
  "Item6": false
}
```

the third one :

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5f0f561256efe82f5082252d"
  },
  "Item1": false,
  "Item2": "",
  "Item3": 3,
  "Item4": [
    {
      "Name": "TYPE",
      "Value": "QUESTION"
    },
    {
      "Name": "QUESTION",
      "Value": "What is your last name?"
    },
    {
      "Name": "CORRECT_ANSWER",
      "Value": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "ANSWER_1",
      "Value": "name one"
    },
    {
      "Name": "ANSWER_2",
      "Value": "name two"
    }
  ],
  "Item5": [
    10
  ],
  "Item6": false
}
```

What I'm trying here is to make query with aggregation approach and I only want to focus on Item4 for exactly ("Name": "QUESTION") and the value (the question) for identifying the duplication.
The idea is to looking for duplication in the the question itself only ("What is your name?") in our example here. and I don't want to specify witch question because there are long list of them.
I'm looking just for the duplicated questions no mater what is the question look like.
I used the following approach but still I cannot narrow down the output to be only related to question and its value in order to delete the duplicate in the another step.

```
db.collections.aggregate([{ $unwind: "$Item4" }, {$group: { _id: { QUESTION: "$Item4.Name.4", Value: "$Item4.Value.4" }}}]).pretty()
```

I'm executing from mongo shell directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following aggregation will list all the documents (the `_id`s) which have the duplicates of `"Item4.Value"` for the condition `"Item4.Name": "QUESTION"`.

```
db.test.aggregate( [ 
  { 
    $unwind: "$Item4" 
  }, 
  { 
    $match: { "Item4.Name": "QUESTION" } 
  }, 
  { 
    $group: { 
        _id: { "Item4_Value": "$Item4.Value" }, 
        ids: { $push: "$_id" } 
    } 
  },
  { 
    $match: { $expr: { $gt: [ { $size: "$ids" }, 1 ] } } 
  }
] )
```

Answer (score 0):

It works! thanks a lot. I add it to the rest of code as below :

```
db.test.find().count() 

const duplicatesIds = []; 

db.test.aggregate( [ 
        { 
          $unwind: "$Item4" 
        }, 
        { 
          $match: { "Item4.Name": "QUESTION" } //here is the trick...to filter the array to pass only the condition "Item4.Name": "QUESTION".
        }, 
        {
          $group: {
              _id: { "Item4_Value": "$Item4.Value" }, 
              ids: { $push: "$_id" }  
          }
        }
  ], 
    { 
     allowDiskUse: true 
    }
).forEach(function (doc) { 
    doc.ids.shift(); 
    doc.ids.forEach(function (dupId) {
        duplicatesIds.push(dupId); 
    })
});
printjson(duplicatesIds);

db.test.remove({_id:{$in:duplicatesIds}}) 

db.test.find().count()
```